# HTTP code for 'more information required'

Tags: http, http-error

What is an appropriate error code when the server finds that the presented information is **correct** but **insufficient** to successfully serve the request? The Client should come back with more context/information.

412 (Precondition Failed) and 428 (Precondition Required) come close, but are tightly coupled with conditions in HTTP header.
422 (Unprocessable Entity) seems to be the closest, but its generic.

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably treat it like any other correct-but-ultimately-wrong request: `400 Bad Request`. The response body can clarify: `{"errors": {"foo": "missing"}}`.

Comment: Thanks, but its not an error scenario. Suppose client was supposed to send info1, which the client did. Now Administrator changes the client configuration on server to expect info1 and info2, which the client is not aware of. Should this be considered as error or a request to send complete info again?

Comment: I understand the impetus to say "what you sent is fine, but I need more". But that is pretty much the same as with any partially filled out form or other request that's *missing data*. In a partially filled out form scenario, a typical server response is to validate the submitted data and return error codes where the submitted data is wrong, **or no further comment where the submitted data is correct**, and additionally "missing" errors for any required data that was not submitted.

Comment: If you can't fulfil the request, it's an error. What exactly is an old client going to do with the 'partial-error' status anyway? It needs updating to send the full request. Telling it it's half-right doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @user207421 client is capable of sending the complete request. Its just that it doesn't know what info is needed based on configuration on server.

Comment: Why is "being generic" a problem? Just add a response body with the details. Hint: there's a JSON media ype for that.